# PHP preg_match cannot match username

Tags: php, regex

I am building a small login system and I cannot validate the input username. Here is the code

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$/',$username) === 0){
        header('Location: index.php?error=2');
}
```

I want the username to be of length 3 to 16 and contain only alpha numerics , - and _ chars
for example

```
us        - Invalid
<user     - Invalid
us<er     - Invalid
/user     - Invalid
!user     - Invalid
//user    - Invalid
user      - Valid
user-name - Valid
user_name - Valid
1user     - Valid
```

However the above code does not return me to the index page if I input an invalid username.

Here is how the code looks like after the first comments:

```
$username = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Match username which contains letters and number and has length
//3 to 16 characters
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$/',$username)){
        header('Location: index.php?error=2');
}
```

Comment: It should work, do you test the right `$username`? The code seem to be ok. Do you have any output before this code?

Comment: You MUST not output anything else before the `header` directive! Did you%)P?

Comment: I am not doing any output before the `header`

Comment: Dont do if ===0 `IF(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$/',$username)` is  enough

Comment: @Mihai: in this case you need to use `!preg_match()`, but it doesn´t solve the task.

Comment: Also before the snippet above, I am declaring some functions and variables. After I commented them out the code worked. Why is that?

Comment: There is likely some kind of output before the header. This could be a whitespace, including linebreaks. You could try checking where it happens using [headers_sent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)